# A sequence of Lipschitz functions converge uniformly to $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Can I assert the existence of a sequence of Lipschitz functions $\{f_n\}$ that converge uniformly to $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{2}$. If so how? And how should I construct a concrete example?

Answer (score 2):

$$ f_n(x) = \sqrt{x+\frac{1}{4^n}} $$
is a Lipschitz function on $[0,1]$, and:
$$ f_n(x)-\sqrt{x} = \frac{\frac{1}{4^n}}{f_n(x)+\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

---

As an alternative, you may also exploit the concavity of $\sqrt{x}$, giving that
$$ f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\text{if}&0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{n},\\ \sqrt{x}&\text{if}&\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1\end{array}\right.$$
is a Lipschitz function for which $0\leq f_n(x)-\sqrt{x}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$

---

Yet another chance is given by taking $f_1(x)=\frac{1+x}{2}$ (the tangent line in $x=1$) and:
$$ f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{f_n(x)+\frac{x}{f_n(x)}}{2} $$
just like in the babylonian method for square root extraction. Convergence is really fast:
$$ 0\leq f_n(x)-\sqrt{x}\leq \frac{1}{2^n} $$
and the Lipschitz constant of $f_n(x)$ is $\frac{1}{3}\left(2^n-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$. You may check by induction that:
$$ f_n(x) = \sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^{2^n}+(1-\sqrt{x})^{2^n}}{(1+\sqrt{x})^{2^n}-(1-\sqrt{x})^{2^n}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The part of $x^{1/2}$ that is non-Lipschitz is near $x=0$.  Flatten it out a little.